# Python Basic Loop Issue

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to get the below code to run in Python and I keep getting a error at the return n point. Can someone please look at the code and see where I messed up at?

```
while True:
    n = input(prompt)
    try:
        n = float(n)
        if n < n1 or n > n2:
            print('Error. Input was out of range')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('Error. Please enter a number')
return n

def main():
    average = 0
    count = 0
    while(True):
        name = input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish: ")
    if name == '*':
        break
        scores = 0
        scores += getPosFloat('Please enter a score for ' + name + ': ', 0, 100)
        scores += getPosFloat('Please enter another score for ' + name + ': ', 0, 100)
        scores += getPosFloat('Please enter another score for ' + name + ': ', 0, 100)
    print('The average score for ' + name+ ' is: %.2f' % (scores/3))
    #please give the proper argument
    average += getPosFloat('Please enter average score for ' + name + ': ', 0, 100)
    count += 1
    if count!=0:
        print("The class average is: ",(average)/count)
main()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `prompt` is not defined. Please share your full code. Have a look also at *[mcve]*.

Comment: Where are you expecting `return n` to return to?

Comment: I am expecting to have n return the number that was entered in by the user

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a value outside a function. (I'm assuming that is all the code you have since that is all you provided )

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry still really new to the coding side of things

Comment: You have no values assigned to n1 and n2. Honestly the first part before the main() function seems like it has no importance to the rest of the code. Check if you have the right code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your function definition.  It looks like you should have

```
def getPosFloat(prompt, n1, n2):
    while True:
        n = input(prompt)
        try:
            n = float(n)
            if n < n1 or n > n2:
                print('Error. Input was out of range')
            else:
                break
        except:
            print('Error. Please enter a number')
    return n
```

before your `main()`  There are still other errors, but that will get you started